# Apple Mach-O Linker Error With Parse

Tags: ios, xcode

I need some assistance.  I added Parse SDK and it works fine during testing. When I attempt to build it, it gives me four 'Apple Mach-O Linker' errors:

> ld: warning: ignoring file
>   /Users/Amirhosein/Downloads/ParsePlatform-PushTutorial-63133fb/iOS/Parse.framework/Parse,
>   missing required architecture arm64 in file
>   /Users/Amirhosein/Downloads/ParsePlatform-PushTutorial-63133fb/iOS/Parse.framework/Parse
>   (3 slices) Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PFPush", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PFInstallation", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Parse", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code
>   1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: check whether parse.framework is added

Comment: for me the parse framework is working for arm64

Answer (score 2):

It sounds as if your library is not built for 64-bit iOS but you're trying to use that setting for your app.  Try removing arm64 from the architecture entry in your build settings.

Comment: i don't know who you are but i will find you and will hug you. You saved me from a major headache.

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning the code and then building again solve the problem for me!